# Implementing dropout in Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am currently working with a convolutional neural network built in Theano. Dropout is a regularization technique in which node outputs are masked with a certain probability, and to my understanding the **masks should be applied in the forward direction as well as during back propagation.**

Since I am currently working in Theano, the back propagation step is replaced by the T.grad function which uses automatic differentiation to calculate the gradient of the model. In the few examples that I have found online, they only mask the values in the forward direction and don't consider the dropout mask at all during the gradient calculation step. What sort of effects will this have on the network and if I wanted to include the mask in the gradient calculation how would I do that? The code I have now is mainly based on the code supplied by the Lisa Lab in their deep learning tutorial.

Comment: usually such questions should include some code of yours.  I would suggest looking at more examples. look at "lasagne"...it's a framework built on top of theano with decent support and code you can look at. when using dropout, only the units that are active will be updated.  during test, all units are used but outputs are scaled according to the dropout ratio.

Comment: Any reason you are doing this in pure Theano vs. [Lasagne](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne)?  Implementing dropout in Lasagne is a one-liner.

Comment: @user1269942 A lot of the code I have isn't that useful isolated so I didn't want to post something useless. But thank you I'll definitely try out Lasagne or at least have a lot at how they implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of multiplication of two variables such as x*y, x has y gradient and vice versa. Dropout uses masking of an output of the nodes which is the multiplication of mask and output of the node. While doing grad, it will take care by theano itself. [dropout implementation in theano](https://github.com/Sentient07/theano-dropout)